# SwiftUI GeometryReader makes its content loaded twice

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader

How are you doing?

Please consider the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

   var body: some View {

      NavigationView {
          GeometryReader { geometry in
              ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  ViewOne()
                     .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
              }
          }
      }
   }
}

struct ViewOne: View {

   init() {
       print("View one init")
   }

   var body: some View {
       VStack(alignment: .center) {
           Text("This is View one")
               .font(.system(size: 50))
       }
   }
}
```

My question is simple: Why is ViewOne built two times inside a GeometryReader and only once outside of a GeometryReader?

First, I thought that the view needed to be created once, and then a second time taking in consideration the GeometryReader sizes, however, if you have a more complex content within ViewOne, things get messy.

Any ideas??

Thanks for your time and help on this SwiftUI friends!!

Answer (score 3):

It is not due to `GeometryReader` (consider below variant or put in into any *xStack*), it is because everything in placed into `NavigationView`, which makes own complex layout. Moreover you have not rely how many times `View.init` is called - View is struct, value, it can be created/copied many times during views layout & rendering (Apple promised to make it optimal, but that's it).

**So, just don't put anything heavy (on unrelated) into `View.init` (and into View at all). Use for that other design patterns.**

```
struct TestGeometryReaderBuilder: View {

   var body: some View {
          GeometryReader { geometry in
              ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  ViewOne()
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
              }
          }
    }
}

struct ViewOne: View {

   init() {
       print("ViewOne> init")
   }

   var body: some View {
       print("ViewOne> build")
       return VStack(alignment: .center) {
           Text("This is View one")
               .font(.system(size: 50))
       }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, while debugging an app, it makes it more complicated since breakpoints will hit two times and I just find this behavior not "normal". It became a habit to have light init method and heavier .onAppear()